# How can I find next element after element with specific class

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to know which element will be after element with specific class.

`nextSibling` property is not my case, because if I have `<h3>` element as next element he will not be in `nextSibling` property.

```
<div>
  <div class="specificClass"></div>
  <h3>header</h3>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

If there is a way to find next element without looping through parent container?
  **No jQuery please.)**

Comment: `nextSibling` takes (white space) text nodes into account, so you more likely want https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a Pen to demonstrate how `nextElementSibling` works.

> Note that `nextElementSibling` will find any Element even Input, Script etc.

[Here is the Pen](https://codepen.io/Tibixx/pen/rdGrKE)

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for `nextElementSibling` and not `nextSibling`. 
`nextElementSibling` will look for next sibling ELEMENT whereas `nextSibling` will look for anything next (can be comment, text etc.)